# Read file with variable name C++

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am trying to open a different file for different levels and need a variable name to do so. I tried the following but gave the error: "no suitable conversion from string to const char"

```
void loadMap(){
    //string levelname;
    //levelname = '../Levels/Level' + level;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("../Levels/Level" + level + ".txt", "r"); //THIS LINE IS GIVING THE ERROR
    char section[80];
    int index = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    while(true){
        fscanf(file, "%s", section);
        if(strcmp(section, "[Victor]") == 0){
            while(true){
                fscanf(file, "%d%d%d", &index, &x, &y);
                if(index == -1){
                    break;
                }
                victor.x = x;
                victor.y = y;
            }
        }
```

...
...
//more code

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should be using `std::ifstream`, it's the C++ way(tm).
Secondly, concatenation of strings should be done using `std::stringstream` from the header `sstream`, here's an example of how this could be accomplished:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::string level = "test";
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss<<"../Levels/Level"<<level<<".txt";

    std::ifstream file(ss.str());
    if(!file.is_open()) {
        // error
    } else {
        // continue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"../Levels/Level" + level + ".txt" is evaluated to string object but fopen() takes const char* as first argument. You can fix it in following way:

```
fopen(("../Levels/Level" + level + ".txt").c_str(), "r");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE *file;
char buf[50];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf),"%s%d.txt","../Levels/Level",level);
file = fopen(buf, "r");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.